# Unable to import module 'abc': /var/task/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: ELF file's phentsize not the expected size

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a script written in python which is using PostgreSQL.Script is working fine on the local system but while uploading script to the AWS lambda it throws the following error:

Unable to import module 'abc': /var/task/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: ELF file's phentsize not the expected size

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Bummed to see no one's answered it yet!